# php class do once for all instances

Tags: methods, properties, static, instance, self

So I have a class whose constructor downloads some xml and reads it into properties for the class to work with. I'm instantiating this class a couple of times and this time-consuming job is done three times in exactly the same manner. Could I avoid it somehow (I guess with a static method/properties)? My class should only once go get the properties and then every instance could use them. I feel I should put the code out of my constructor in a static function, but how it's done exactly, I don't know, since I always get errors.

```
class MyClass {
   protected $xml_file;
   protected $xml_derived_array;

   public function __construct($param1, $param2, $param3) {
   //get xml_file and make xml_derived_array with it
   //do some other stuff with parameters and properties such as $xml_derived_array
   }
}
```

Should become something like: (but how should I call the static properties in my __construct and how should I set the properties in the static function?)

```
class MyClass {
   protected static $xml_file;
   protected static $xml_derived_array;

   protected static function get_xml() {
   //get xml_file and make xml_derived_array with it (?how exactly?)
   }

   public function __construct($param1, $param2, $param3) {
   self::get_xml();
   //do some other stuff with parameters and properties such as $xml_derived_array (?how exactly?)
   }
}
```

**Edit**
This is how it is now working:

```
class MyClass {
   protected static $xml_file;
   protected static $xml_derived_array = array();

   public function __construct($param1, $param2, $param3) {
      if (!self::$xml_file) {
         self::$xml_file = simplexml_load_file('xml_file.xml');
         self::$xml_derived_array[0] = self::$xml_file->title;
      }
      echo self::$xml_derived_array[0].$param1;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a static method. Just check if the property has a value in constructor and if not get the xml file and process it.

```
class MyClass {
   protected static $xml_file;
   protected static $xml_derived_array = array();

   public function __construct($param1, $param2, $param3) {
      if (! count(self::$xml_derived_array)){
          //get xml_file and make xml_derived_array with it
          //do some other stuff with parameters and properties such as $xml_derived_array
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be self::$xml_derived_array ? Without $ it doesn't work. See my edit to see how I'm doing it now and it works.